# How to restore a list after making changes

Tags: python, list, unlink

I am trying to change a list of lists(matrix) but keep a saved version so I can undo the changes I make. However, when I change matrix, the saved version is changing as well.
Here is my code:

```
    matrix = [[14, 12, 13, 15, 16, 13, 12, 14],
             [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
             [4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4]]
    saved_matrix = matrix
    matrix[4][2] = 8
    matrix = saved_matrix
    print matrix
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Since lists are mutable you are dealing with references to the objects. You can save a copy of a nested list structure in a few ways - here are two,

```
saved_matrix = [row[:] for row in matrix]
```

And,

```
import copy
saved_matrix = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this

```
saved_matrix = matrix
```

you will just have the same object, with two different names...

To duplicate your object, you can use the `copy` standard lib: http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

The code will look like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy
saved_matrix = deepcopy(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the matrix using `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
saved_matrix = deepcopy(matrix)
```

Comment: Thank You! I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: It is always nice to look for the built in modules before starting to code it yourself...